# HTML unreachable DOM node, Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to extract some data from a website using javascript and there is something confusing I have never seen before. The problem is accessing the nodeValue which is text.

The table example is like this:

```
<td>

"

    SOME DATA

                "


</td>
```

And I'm not able to reach this data

```
document.getElementsByClassName("alt-row")[20].childNodes[4].textContent[45];
```

I've tried to loop through everything with no luck, just returning spaces...
I'd really appreciate a solution for this.

Thanks for all answers in advance!

Comment: How do you know those are the correct indices?

Answer (score 1):

If `"alt-row"` is a `<tr>`, then you need to consider that when you use `.childNodes`, you're also getting text nodes with the row cells.

Use the `.cells` collection instead to get the fifth cell.

```
//                     use .cells----------------v
document.getElementsByClassName("alt-row")[20].cells[4].textContent[45];
```

---

And then from there it depends on what you want with the `textContent`. Not sure why you're looking up the character at index `45`.

Also, you'll want to be certain that the indices you're using are correct. You should `console.log()` the various values to double check.

Comment: Also, some browsers don't support accessing characters of a string using an index. But I think those same browsers don't support *textContent* either. :-/

Comment: @RobG: You're right. When it gets to that point, I'd probably suggest OP select the nested text node, and get its data. `...cells[4].firstChild.data` and then `.charAt(45)` to get the character if that's what's desired.

Answer (score 0):

`.textContent` is a string, not a collection of text nodes; `.textContent[45]` will get the 46th character in the real text. Looks like you just want `.textContent`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, well I tried that, but what I get is 
"

", just an empty spaces without the text inside.

Comment: @user2818626: Have you looked at what `.childNodes[4]` is in your console? (And did you mean `.children[4]`?)